# should i use action or create reusable function for CRUD in React Hook

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand React hook (useReducer, useEffect), what is the best way to create crud to hit on API with React hook? 
should I create the function for fetch, delete, add, update in action ? then call it on reducer ? or create another reusable function and call it on the action ? or create reusable function crud and use it on components?

let say that I want to add a task

```
async function addTask(payload){
   try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(endppoint, payload)
     return data
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
}

async function getTask() {
   try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(endppoint)
     return data
   } catch(e){
     console.log(e)
   }
}
```

where i should call those functions if I use React Hook? 
i have read some articles but i just want to make sure those, for example, to hit to API

Comment: Why did you tag redux?